# Strange behaviour with monospaced font in UILabel when changing text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uislider, monospace

I have a strange issue when using `monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize:weight:)`

I have one `UISlider` and one `UILabel` in my `UIViewController`. The Label is showing the current value of the slider + some description text. When changing the slider's value, the text of `myLabel` is shaking left and right a bit. I would expect the `myLabel`'s text to not shake left and right, since I am using `monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize:weight:)`.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mySlider: UISlider!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myLabel.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .bold)
    }

    @IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        myLabel.text = String(format: "%.5f is the actual Value of the Slider", sender.value)
    }
}
```

**GIF about the jiggle:**

[image: jiggling monospaced text]

Any suggestions? Am I missing something?

Comment: You can right align your text to avoid this kind of behavior which is due to the different text width when you use your slide

Comment: @Y.Bonafons this does only work if the description text is behind the slider's value. When i change it so that the slider's value is in front of the description text and right align the text i have the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a horrible bug and it's caused by the monospaced font being **bold**. Setting the weight to regular solves this problem.

```
myLabel.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular)
```

If you still want to use a bold font, consider using a non-standard monospaced font.

Comment: This works. Thank you very much. Is this bug reported yet?

Comment: @T.Werb It's not yet reported AFAIK.

Comment: Hmm? It was rock solid for me when I tried it with Xcode 9.2.

Comment: I am using Xcode 9.2 and it is shaking. Not really heavy shaking but it is.

Comment: @vacawama Did you try to run the exact code the OP had provided? If you zoom on the text, it clearly jiggles around when being bold. I'm using Xcode 9.2 as well.

Comment: NVM.  When I used manual zoom (face very near screen) I can see it.  Weird.  I was expecting the shaking to be larger.

Comment: @vacawama Try [screen zoom](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/02/enable-screen-zoom-in-mac-os-x-lion/) for occurrences like this.